# Javascript function with $.each inside and return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value, each

I want to use $.each inside a function. But i have problems with the return value, which should be overwritten in the each function.

```
function validate_voting_stars() {
    $error = false;
    $.each( $('input.rr'), function(index,value){
        vote = $(this).val();
        if( $.isNumeric($(this).val() ) && vote < 6 ) {
            return;
        } else {
            $error = true;
        }
    })
    return $error;
}
```

I think, that the firing of the return value is not waiting for finishing the each function of jQuery. Is there a way, how i can solve this?  For testing i added the return inside the each function, but this is not working too

Any ideas?

Comment: do you want to return false if any one of the input is invalid

Comment: Yes. If one of the input ".rr" is empty or not_numeric...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function validate_voting_stars() {
    $error = false;
    $.each( $('input.rr'), function(index,value){
        vote = $(this).val();
        if( !$.isNumeric($(this).val() ) || vote > 6 ) {
            $error = true;
            return false;
        }
    })
    return $error;
}
```